# How can I disable a button when I press another button

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a beginner in app scripting and I have a question.
How can I disable a button when I press another button.

I tried many different ways, but I can't get it to work.

Can you help me?

My code is large.  Should I paste it here?

Comment: Please provide more information.  Your question is too vague

Comment: Which service? HtmlService? UiService? It would help to post the code around your button definitions and handlers. (You DO have handlers, right? Maybe that's the problem!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in UiApp you can use [clientHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/client-handler) to do that very easily...
example code goes like this :

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var btn1 = app.createButton('button1');
  var btn2 = app.createButton('button2');
  var clientHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(btn1).setEnabled(false);
  btn2.addClickHandler(clientHandler);

  return app.add(btn1).add(btn2);
}
```

Note : the comments above are right... your question was indeed too vague.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you will need to post some relevant code before anyone will be able to help you.
2. Broadly speaking, a good logical approach to achieving what you want to do, is to use the event that occurs, or state that is invoked by clicking the first button, to run script that will disable your second button.

This can be done many different ways. Client Side, Server Side.. it all really depends on context as to which is right for your situation.